# Error solving Matrix equation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm writing my own Newton-Raphson algorithm in Python using `sympy` and `numpy`.

The code is below but you can ignore this and skip on to the error:

**CODE**

```
def newtonRhapson(fncList, varz, x0):

    jacob = []

    for fnc in fncList:
        vec = []
        for var in varz:
            res = fnc.diff(var)
            for i in range(len(varz)):
                res = res.subs(varz[i], x0[i])
            vec.append(res)
        jacob.append(numpy.array(vec, dtype='float64'))

    fx0=[]

    for fnc in fncList:
        res2 = fnc
        for i in range(len(varz)):
            res2 = res2.subs(varz[i], x0[i])
        fx0.append(res2)

    j = jacob
    f = fx0

    print j
    print ''
    print f

    print numpy.linalg.solve(j,f).tolist()
```

The arguments to the function are:

`fncList` - a python list of functions using `Sympy` symbols

`varz` - a list containing those symbols (variables)

`x0` - initial guess

**ERROR**

Up until the point where we `print` `j` and `f` it works fine and prints the following:

```
[array([-9.13378682, -5.91269838]), array([ 4.84401379,  1.01980286])]

[-5.15598620617611, 5.13378681611922]
```

when I run:

```
newtonRhapson([5*cos(a)+6*cos(a+b)-10, 5*sin(a)+6*sin(a+b)-4], [a,b], [0.7,0.7])
```

But on running the line:

```
print numpy.linalg.solve(j,f).tolist()
```

I get the error:

```
File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 384, in solve
r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc solve1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is in your second `for` loop.

```
for fnc in fncList:
    res2 = fnc
    for i in range(len(varz)):
        res2 = res2.subs(varz[i], x0[i])
    fx0.append(res2)
```

When you append to `fx0`, you need to ensure that you are appending the same type (`float64`) such that NumPy can compute the determinant of your system with LAPACK (*see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29182790/4686625) for more info*). You are currently appending `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>` - your errror message is telling you that you have an incorrect type signature for usage.

**To correct this issue**, you can simply append `numpy.array` with a `dtype` specification for `float64` as you did above

```
for fnc in fncList:
    res2 = fnc
    for i in range(len(varz)):
        res2 = res2.subs(varz[i], x0[i])
    fx0.append(numpy.array(res2, dtype='float'))
```

Comment: A comment, for googlers - This is the same error you will get for many numpy functions, where you have the wrong data type (for me, it was a np.linalg.pinv(x), where x was incorrectly an object dtype)